# URL Rewrite - Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a news (blog) site that returns urls in the following format when individual posts are selected:

```
website.net/sitenews.php?q=posts/view/postname/12
```

I am seeking to rewrite the url so that it reads:

```
website.net/sitenews.php/posts/view/postname/12
```

or any other way where the `?q=` is removed for purpose of removing the `?` so that the url can be accessed by facebook's like button as the facebook url linter does not parse query strings.

In the htdocs .htaccess file in the root directory I have tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=  

RewriteRule (.*) website.net/sitenews.php/$1? [R=301]
```

This successfully removes the `q=?` however the rest of the string (`posts/view/postname/12`) is not returned and the url now looks as follows:

```
 website.net/sitenews.php/sitenews.php
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to help me complete this url_rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

R=301 will redirect with https status 301
L will make last rule
NE is for no escaping query string

%1 is capture group for query string q= (whatever comes after q=)
$1 is your REQUEST_URI
```

Comment: anubhava, the code above generates website.net/sitenews.php/posts/view/postname/12/posts/view/postname/12/posts/view/postname/12

Comment: @Hamy: Sorry I had a minor typo in above rule which was causing infinite re-directions. Please see my edited answer above. I have tested it and it should work without problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I get rid of the **.php** as well in between the generated link website.net/sitenews.php/posts/view/posts ?

Comment: @Rajat: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062537/htacces-rewrite-rule-remove-php-ending/6062909#6062909 if that doesn't meet your requirements then pls create a new question on SO and send me the question link in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any CMS, like wordpress, or joomla or SE, then you have option to do that else you need to have an `.htaccess` file where you can write the code, refer this links

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/2545.htm

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=htaccess+change+the+url&aq=0p&aqi=p-p1g4&aql=&oq=htaccess+&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c875dd2b8adea15a