# Apache .htacces Rewrite Rule to Remove .php File Extensions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The title explains the basics, now, here comes the problem:

I have many files that look like this:

```
<?php include 'mynavbar.php';   
include 'myheader.php';    
include 'myfirstline.php'; 
include 'mybuttons.php';   
include 'myadvert.php'; 
include 'myimg.php';?>
```

And I can't edit all the files and remove the `.php`. How can I not show the `.php` in the **address bar** but still be able to include the pages by using the `.php` ending

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following code should work for you in .htaccess file to hide `.php` extension:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also remember that these rules will have **NO** impact in your php includes eg:  `include 'myheader.php';`

It is because those includes are processed by php itself and don't go through Apache.

Comment: I've tried like 10 rewrite rules and none of them worked. This one works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are kind, can you tell me how can I also remove the "/index" for the homepage? ;;)

Comment: About `could I also remove the "/index" for the homepage` Sure I will try to put that rule condition also. Will update the answer in a short while.

Comment: @Cristy: Edited my answer above to take care of removal of `/index` pls verify.

Comment: This works wonderfully, except in the case of navigating to `/foo/` - The trailing slash makes it error trying to look for `foo/.php` Anyway to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: @couzzi: Pls try edited response for better handling of `/foo/` kind of URIs with trailing slashes.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the response — this didn't seem to do it. Now `/foo/` `/foo` and `/foo.php` all come back as Not Found. Any ideas?

Comment: @couzzi: Make another edit, pls try it now. (Though I think changing an accepted answer is not a very healthy practice).

Answer (score 4):

The following RewriteRules will *assume* the PHP extension for any file that is not otherwise matched. It should go at the bottom of your RewriteRules in your .htaccess file.

```
# Force PHP extension if not a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^((.*/)*[^./]+)/*$ $1.php [L]
```

This is for URL Rewriting. As far as `include` statements, you still need the PHP extension as these are *physical* file paths. If you need to so something fancy there, you should look into symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking the correct path for fixing the problem you trying to solve.

If I understood well, what you want to do is having an url like :

```
http://example.com/my/url
```

instead of (for example):

```
http://example.com/my/url.php
```

If this is the case, what you should look for is [rewrite url](http://www.google.com/search?q=rewrite%20url)

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. You  are not adding anything towards the community.

Comment: Thank you for poiting that out. I should have copied something that exists already 200^2000 times on the web just to have something more useful than an url to share. Because I'm sure you believe my answer is incorrect? Good boy ...

Comment: But well, I must say thanks for telling me why you downvoted my answer, at least, you shared your thought.

Comment: I will cancel  the downvote once you edit it (because SOF is not allowing me to do so), but please edit your answer and post the solution at-least. You are basically telling the OP to search in Google. What is the use of this site then? Atleast try to post the  url which seems correct :-)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I don't think it's useful to change my comment : to what? If I edit it to insert the solution, I will just copy the accepted answer. The accepted answer is complete for his request, mine was more generalist, because at the time, I believed the question needed a better generalist answer (via google) than a specific one. I thought the user asking the question was starting with .htaccess/url-rewriting and redirecting him on more links than just his specific answer was more helpful. That's why.

Comment: I accept your downvote because 1. you presented yourself as the downvoter (which is a great step) 2. You explained why. Most of the people who downvote don't take the time to explain why. I believe it's when you downvote something that you need, more than ever, to explain why, because you help the author understand his errors (or why you disagree with him).

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Here's some upvote for your comments atleast :-)