# HTACCESS remove ext html from url

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url

I have urls like these:

```
site.com/user.html?id=2

site.com/user.html
```

all i need is to return the same page removing ".html" so:

```
site.com/user
```

in case of somenthing after ".html" i need to add back slash

```
site.com/user/?id=2
```

is there anyway to do this in htaccess?

i'm only using js and html pages (no server side languages)

Comment: have you tried this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062537/htacces-rewrite-rule-remove-php-ending
(try replacing php with html) ...

Comment: doesn't works cause don't know where to put site url :P

Comment: from site.com/asd/index.html i'm returned to site.com/index

Comment: you need to put the htaccess then also in the asd folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy, paste and edit from [Apache .htacces Rewrite Rule to Remove .php File Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062537/htacces-rewrite-rule-remove-php-ending)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# to make `/path/index.html` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: the problem is i'm loading files via jquery load('top.html'); doesn't works

Comment: all files are under same /path

Comment: for urls is ok for jquery seems not

Comment: cause load('top.html') redirects me to top file which doesn't exist

Comment: Well this will be complicated to achieve, you can try to use some filters in the htaccess...
But can't you use PHP ?
With php it would be server side and there won't be a problem ...
<?php include("top.php"); ?>