# HT Access removing .php extension conflicts with custom error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm currently using this in my htaccess file so that the .php extensions do not have to be shown in the URL. This works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

What I want to do is change the default 404 error page to a custom one.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my_site/public/custom404.php
```

The problem I'm encountering here is the above code only works if the re-write rule is removed from the file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because you append the `.php` extension unconditionally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache .htacces Rewrite Rule to Remove .php File Extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062537/apache-htacces-rewrite-rule-to-remove-php-file-extensions)

Comment: How can i correct the code so that it is conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace you rewrite rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```