# Grabbing Querystrings while using ModRewrite with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm using URL rewriting through .htaccess on my site. Then I submit through PayPal's ExpressPay and get something like the following returned:

```
http://mydomian.com/cart/success?token=EC-123456789&PayerID=123456789
```

The /cart and /success are great, but is there an easy way to grab the "token" an "PayerID" variables?

Here's the .htaccess I'm working with:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?load=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?load=$1&query=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?load=$1&query=$2&query2=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `[QSA]` to each of your rules, and change your third rule to have these flags: `[L,QSA]`. This will make it so the query string you get back from PayPal will be appended and you'll be able to access them from index.php.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use {QUERY_STRING} as the condition http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

Answer (score 0):

See: [URL Rewrite - Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606916/url-rewrite-query-string)

Or just have mydomain.com/cart/success grab $_GET['token']

Comment: Your rewrite is eliminating it then? Might be easier if you share your htaccess info in your question.