# How to rewrite page name with with in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess with php, I need to rewrite the below url

```
 freelancers.php?new=user
```

as

```
 register.php?new=freelancer
```

can any one help me out on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: this is not about rewriting with friendly url but I wanted to rewrite the complete path like from freelancer.php page to register.php.

Comment: Yes. That would be included, since the dupe target I linked is extremely broad: the general pattern is basically the same one. "My URL sections aren't exactly the same as in the example" is not much of a distinction to make.

Comment: you are using same page with different pattern for query string but I need different pages with different query strings

Comment: @NathanTuggy The linked question does not give any information about the query string. I'll see if I can find a better dupe target.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497184/replacing-a-querystring-parameter-value-using-mod-rewrite or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606916/url-rewrite-query-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /register.php\?new=freelancer\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ freelancers.php?new=user [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^new=user$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^freelancers\.php$ register.php?new=freelancer [L,NC]
```